# Xcode 15.0 beta 5 always generates GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift

Tags: xcode, xcode15

Xcode15.0 beta 5 doesn't respect Build Settings for disabling asset generation.
Asset generated in GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift conflicts with asset generated by swiftgen.

```
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GENERATE_ASSET_SYMBOLS = NO;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GENERATE_ASSET_SYMBOL_FRAMEWORKS = "";
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GENERATE_SWIFT_ASSET_SYMBOL_EXTENSIONS = NO;
```